# MySQL InnoDB: Primary Key + unsigned integer size?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a MySQL InnoDB table that looks like this:

`key`, `value`

`key` is an auto incremenet integer (0 to 5,000,000)
`value` is an unsigned int16 value (0 to 65535)

what would be the size (in KB) taken by every row of this table?

Answer (score 4):

Each `INT` is 4 byte, each `SMALLINT` is 2 bytes. So each row is 6 bytes (I'm not going to give it to you in KB). I assume that `key` is also a primary key index. InnoDb indices have an overhead of roughly 1.4, so each row adds another 6 bytes (roughly) to the key.

If a column can be NULL, then there's another byte for each row.

Comment: wow, that's a lot of space!  is there any way to store this info with much, much less space?

Comment: 12 bytes per row of data is a lot of space? Even if you're storing records for all 5 million keys, that's only 60 MB.

Answer (score 0):

According to [10.5 Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html) you need 3 bytes for the key (MEDIUMINT) and 2 bytes for the value (SMALLINT).